# Books on reversing with GDB?

Tags: disassembly, gdb

I'm getting started with some reverse engineering lately, especially on Linux and ELF format, but I'm struggling here.

For now I'm only using GDB to disassemble binaries, and even though I can read and understand the assembly code in general, I don't know "where" to look, or what register to check to find the flag (I'm talking about CTFs here).

What I'm asking for are books or videos, something to get me used to GDB and give me the thinking methodology (if there's such a thing).
Thanks!

Comment: There is no such "Look at this register to get the flag" tutorial. Every good CTF is different and require thinking out of the box. Maybe you should try to do some wargames so you can learn step by step and teach yourself by practice what you need to know : https://exploit-exercises.com/nebula/

Comment: I think CTF write-ups about reversing will help you here [1](https://ctftime.org/writeups) [2](https://github.com/ctfs/write-ups-2016) also I highly recommend: [Learning Linux Binary Analysis book](https://www.amazon.com/Learning-Binary-Analysis-elfmaster-ONeill/dp/1782167102) also check [LiveOverflow channel](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLhixgUqwRTjxglIswKp9mpkfPNfHkzyeN) in youtube

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Special for beginners Dennis Yurichev wrote this book:
[**Reverse Engineering for Beginners**](http://beginners.re/Reverse_Engineering_for_Beginners-en.pdf)

You can find it and download on his [site](http://beginners.re/) for free.

> Topics discussed: x86/x64, ARM/ARM64, MIPS, Java/JVM.
>
> Topics touched: Oracle RDBMS, Itanium, copy-protection dongles,
>   LD_PRELOAD, stack overflow, ELF, win32 PE file format, x86-64,
>   critical sections, syscalls, TLS, position-independent code (PIC),
>   profile-guided optimization, C++ STL, OpenMP, win32 SEH.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn reverse engineering on Linux, I highly recommend: Learning Linux Binary Analysis.

It is the only book (that I know of) that goes in depth on the ELF format.

[https://www.amazon.com/Learning-Binary-Analysis-elfmaster-ONeill/dp/1782167102/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1493623237&sr=8-1&keywords=linux+binary+analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1782167102)

Comment: NoStarch recently released [Practical Binary Analysis](https://nostarch.com/binaryanalysis), which also goes in-depth on the ELF format.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommended this position:
[https://www.amazon.com/Practical-Reverse-Engineering-Reversing-Obfuscation/dp/1118787315](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118787315)